# postfix- connection time out

Tags: postfix-mta

Am trying send email to my server to gmail account with postfix with mail command

`echo  "check" | mail -s "check" aryan.kingrockzz@gmail.com`

and email not comming and error is

```
 Sep  1 05:05:24 ns1 postfix/pickup[23268]: 5EC10A2494: uid=0 from=<root@ns1.sloc.in>
    Sep  1 05:05:24 ns1 postfix/cleanup[23345]: 5EC10A2494: message-id=<20160901120524.5EC10A2494@sloc.in>
    Sep  1 05:05:24 ns1 postfix/qmgr[23269]: 5EC10A2494: from=<root@ns1.sloc.in>, size=326, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
    Sep  1 05:05:24 ns1 postfix/error[23338]: 5EC10A2494: to=<aryan.kingrockzz@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.219.26]:25: No route to host)
```

Answer (score 2):

Outgoing traffic on Port 25 might be blocked by your ISP. Quite commonplace.

As the error message says: Your machine cannot reach the target system on port 25.
Try manually:

```
telnet alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
```

Comment: I have a similar issue on my Linode server when I do `telnet` as you asked. It stays on "Trying..." and never gets past that, but when I use my computer it connects fine.

Comment: Your suggestion made me notice that Linode is blocking the traffic, [which they now do](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/11162/is-linode-blocking-port-25) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your internet connection first.
Then find out the interface that internet connection is on. lets assume its `eth0`

```
ip route list
```

if you don't have a default route on that interface, you need to add one.

```
sudo ip route add default dev eth0
```

and then `postqueue -f` to retry the deferred email or try sending a new one.

if you are using a vpn connection to connect your server to the internet your interface probably is `ppp0` , you can check that via `ip a` command.